# Error running linux container on windows 2019 server

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, windows-server-2019

I just install docker on a windows 2019 server to run linux containers.

I follow the this [guide](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-run-docker-containers-on-windows-server-2019/), "Running Linux Containers on Windows Server 2019" chapter. 
When i try to run the bash shell i got the following error:

> docker.exe: failed to register layer: failed to start service utility
>   VM
>   (applydiffe53547ea1d150a4e4afba05378a3a45be5ea769d52fddf03ff25dbd09e43d20d):
>   container
>   e53547ea1d150a4e4afba05378a3a45be5ea769d52fddf03ff25dbd09e43d20d_svm
>   encountered an error during CreateContainer: failure in a Windows
>   system call: The virtual machine could not be started because a
>   required feature is not installed.

Anyone knows what feature is missing?

**Update:**
It seams the problem has to do with a first error on the procedure.
When running:

```
Get-VM WinContainerHost | Set-VMProcessor -ExposeVirtualizationExtensions $true
```

it throws the error:

```
Get-VM : Hyper-V was unable to find a virtual machine with name "ContainerHost".
```

Witch i discard believing that was a guide in the script because there is no command to create this WinContainerHost virtual machine anyware.

Solving is more confusing, there are 2 types of containers, hyper-v and server containers, as posted in this  [guide](https://4sysops.com/archives/create-hyper-v-containers-in-windows-server-2016/). I am not sure what path to follow. I am pretty lost.

Comment: Try ```Get-VM *WinContainerHost* | Set-VMProcessor -ExposeVirtualizationExtensions $true``` instead

Comment: What did you end up doing? Just curious - do you run windows 2019 in the cloud or on the premises? I want to run linux containers on windows 2019 - that is LCOW, but in all articles I found it says it's not ready for production.

Comment: Yes, i found out late. So i give up and setup up a side linux host for linux containers. I am not happy with the solution, but for now there is no other safe way.

Comment: Still no answer to this? My client forces me to use Windows Server but I'm getting the same error as you

Comment: I'm trying this on a Windows Server 2019 provided by AWS (EC2)

Comment: As far as i know is not yet ready for production.

Comment: Anything in the docker service logs? Is hardware virtualization enabled in BIOS?

Answer (score 6):

This is going to sound really DUMB, and I mean DUMB.

I have fixed this issue and I just cannot believe there are questions asked everywhere without and answer.

Basically you need to just create a Virtual machine in Hyper-V. It doesn't need an operating system or any special params.

This is it

```
New-VM -Name WinContainerHost -MemoryStartupBytes 1GB
```

After this the Get-VM works, Docker starts and runs linux containers.

I mean, what can I say!!!

Answer (score 5):

Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to comment/ask more information.

[Hyper-V containers or Moby VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/linux-containers) are mandatory when running Linux containers - virtualization is required to run those containers. So in this case, you can't use "server containers".

Enable VT-x e.g. virtualization from BIOS - mandatory for nested virtualization. With AWS you need [Bare Metal instance](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/running-hyper-v-on-amazon-ec2-bare-metal-instances/).

If these are OK, you could you try already mentioned command

```
Get-VM *WinContainerHost* | Set-VMProcessor -ExposeVirtualizationExtensions $true
```

Instead, if they name differs a bit. If still no success, `Get-VM` command should list all VMs, what is the output?

You can install required modules for running LCOW with

```
Install-WindowsFeature -Name Hyper-V,Containers -IncludeAllSubFeature -IncludeManagementTools
```

And try again. If it still does not exist [here is the script](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/Virtualization-Documentation/tree/master/windows-server-container-tools/Install-ContainerHost) for creating "ContainerHost".

Comment: I'm running into the same problem as OP. When I run Get-VM nothing is returned. I don't get any errors running the "Get-VM *WinContainerHost*" code.

Comment: Stuck in exactly the same place. Get-VM returns nothing, when I assume that something should be creating WinContainerHost. Looked all over the web and there are lots of people asking the same question, but no answer. There is an Import-VM command that is supposed to import from a file, but no details where I can get the said files. It appears we just need one VM running and no info on how to do that